# New line text into the JavaScript

Tags: jquery

Please help. What to change in the code so that you can display text in several lines.

```
var str = 'Result1\nResult2';


var spans = '<span>' + str.split('').join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
$(spans).hide().appendTo('.css-typing').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(100 * i).css({
    display: 'inline',
    opacity: 0
  }).animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 100);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BDR13/1ex7zk9g/4/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow .. Just add <br> Tag in your code to create new line

Comment: Welcome. This option does not work. Or I put it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope I understand what you want, you can do something like

```
var str = 'Result1 Result2 Result3';


var spans = '<span>' + str.split('').join('</span><span>') + '</span>';

spans = spans.replaceAll(" ","<br>");

$(spans).hide().appendTo('.css-typing').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(100 * i).css({
    display: 'inline',
    opacity: 0
  }).animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 100);
});
```

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZBIy.jpg)

Comment: Thank you very much for help. It works perfectly.

Comment: Keeping the original (not fiddle) of `Result1\nResult2` change the `replaceAll` to `.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>")` - but otherwise essentially the same  https://jsfiddle.net/vb7La1pr/